Sudo apt update issue in Parrot OS 5.2
When I do sudo apt-get update in Parrot OS 5.2 I am getting this error. I also change the  /etc/apt/sources.list but still getting the same issue.
My source list is:
deb https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot stable main contrib non-free
deb https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot stable-security main contrib non-free
deb https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot stable-backports main contrib non-free

This is what I changed before. I have LTS but at that time still was getting almost the same issue:
Err:7 https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot stable Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 170.187.249.88 443]
Err:8 https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot stable-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 170.187.249.88 443]
Err:9 https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot stable-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 170.187.249.88 443]
Reading package lists... Done
W: Conflicting distribution: https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot parrot InRelease (expected parrot but got lory)
E: The repository 'https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot stable Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Conflicting distribution: https://deb.parrot.sh/direct/parrot parrot-security InRelease (expected parrot-security but got lory-security)
E: The repository 'https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot stable-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Conflicting distribution: https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot parrot-backports InRelease (expected parrot-backports but got lory-backports)
E: The repository 'https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot stable-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.


You probably shouldn't be using a specialized distro.

Actually seems apt expects "lory" as name instead of "parrot".
Watching documentation

List of Repositories
Although in Parrot it is not necessary (nor recommended) to add new
repositories or modify existing ones, we will see where we can
configure them. In the file system, under the path
/etc/apt/sources.list.d, we find the file parrot.list. The content of
this file should be: stable repository
deb http://deb.parrot.sh/parrot lory main contrib non-free
non-free-firmware #deb-src http://deb.parrot.sh/parrot lory contrib
non-free non-free-firmware
With this, we make sure we have the correct repository list. In this
location the Parrot developers keep the packages updated.

Following documentation, if you change your file configurations you should fix your problem.
The Content of /etc/apt/sources.list.d/parrot.list should be:
deb https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot lory main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
deb https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot lory-security main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
deb https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot lory-backports main contrib non-free non-free-firmware

Note: Please read sources.list.d vs sources.list and check there are no conflicts between the two files
